# What is the difference between createRoot and ReactDOM.render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the difference between ReactDOM.render and createRoot which is introduced in React18?

Comment: Hi bro, I think you can find the answer to this question, just doing a bit of search on google. There is a lot of information about this. For example: [ReactDOM.createRoot vs ReactDOM.render](https://dev.to/fromaline/reactdomcreateroot-reactdomrender-1jg6)

Answer (score 5):

When rendering a React component to the DOM, the methods `createRoot` and `ReactDOM.render` are both used, but they differ in a few ways.

The conventional technique for rendering a React component to a particular DOM element—typically the root of your app—is `ReactDOM.render`. Consider this:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

In this instance, the `<App/>` component is being rendered to the `<div id="root"></div>` element on the page.

`createRoot` : In order to render components in a new way with better performance and better support for concurrent mode, React 17 introduced a new method called `createRoot`. The fundamental operation of `createRoot` is similar to that of `ReactDOM.render`, except that it creates a new root container and returns a reference to it rather than rendering to a particular DOM node. Then, you can render your components to the root container using the returned reference. For instance:

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<App />);
```

In conclusion, the primary distinction between `createRoot` and `ReactDOM.render` is that `createRoot` generates a new root container for rendering components, whereas `ReactDOM.render` renders components directly to a given DOM element.

Answer (score 1):

With `createRoot` and the associated `root.render` function, you can run multiple calls to `render` using the same container DOM element, unlike `ReactDOM.render`, in which every call to `render` requires a new call to the Document API. You can avoid multiple searches of the DOM by storing the root element in a variable, but the new root API with `createRoot` maximizes readability. There are a few other differences, which you can see at https://thelonecoder.dev/javascript/react-js/reactdom-render-vs-createroot/

To use the new root API with `createRoot`, change the legacy root code in your `index.js` to the following:

```
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<App />);
```

Comment: "*in [`ReactDOM.render`] every call to render requires another search of the DOM*" - no. The article you refer to states only that "*If you wanted to run `ReactDOM.render()` multiple times, that would mean passing in the DOM container multiple times as well.*" If you store the DOM node in a variable, just like now you store `root` in a variable, using `ReactDOM.render` does not search the DOM.

Comment: @Bergi my apologies for the mistake! I'll update my answer with the correct information